# Client data isn't passing to the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Forewarning, I'm a newcomer to Javascript, node.js, socket.io. It's been pretty amazing so far. :)

I am trying to create a simple username interface at the moment. Client will enter in their username of choice, click the button and will fire an event that will send the username to the server to be put into an array.

Client connects fine, handshake occurs. Yet the socket isn't emitting the data to the server.

**Server:**

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8888);
var players = [];

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
socket.on('adduser', function(username) {
    players.push(username);
    console.log("Received: " + username);
    });
});
```

**Client:**

```
var socket = io.connect('/socket.io/socket.io.js');
function usernameSubmit(){
console.log("Button pressed");
var textfield = document.getElementById('usernamefield');
var username = textfield.value
if (username != ""){
    console.log(username);
    socket.send('adduser', username);
    console.log("Username submitted.");
}
else
    console.log("Blank username detected.");
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use .emit instead. That way you can pass an object and access it on the server.

Client:

```
if (username != ""){
    console.log(username);
    socket.emit('adduser', { username: username });
    console.log("Username submitted.");
}
```

Server:

```
socket.on('adduser', function(data) {
    players.push(data.username);
    console.log("Received: " + data.username);
});
```

Comment: Not quite; `send` is similar to plain old websockets, in that you can't provide an event name -- it will raise the `message` event instead. You are correct though in that `emit` is what you should use for named events such as `adduser`. You can send a string, an object or invoke a function using both, AFAIK.

Comment: Weird, it still seems like the server isn't receiving anything.

Comment: (Though, I can confirm on the clientside, it's picking up the username just fine.)

Comment: Thanks Linus, I was wrong about the .send. You can either send a 'message' or an object as a JSON string. And iColor, try to use an example from here [link](http://socket.io/#how-to-use) or you have to post your code again.